# difference between pipelining and redirection in linux

Tags: linux, redirect, pipelining

Can anyone tell me the difference? for example:
if I have a file `a.txt` with the following content:

> a
>   b
>   c

what would be the difference between `cat a.txt | cat` and `cat < a.txt`
It seems to me that they all simulate STDIN, is that correct, or are there differences? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Voting to move to Super User, this is not a programming question.

Comment: @unwind uh..yeah it is. Bash is a programming language. This is programming- at a high level.

Comment: The question exists here (where it's more suitable): http://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Piping works from one process to another (the `cat`s in the first example), and hence requires two processes cooperating. Redirection is handled by the shell itself. This can matter when doing things in the shell such as [working with variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 3):

The redirection does not "simulate STDIN".  When you redirect, the file *is* the stdin for the process.  In particular, many programs have different behavior if the input is a regular file than if it is a pipe or a tty, so you may get different behavior.  For example:

```
$ < file perl -E 'say "is a regular file" if -f STDIN'
is a regular file
$ cat file | perl -E 'say "is a regular file" if -f STDIN'
```

Comment: sorry, I am new to this, is it possible that you could explain a bit about your example program, thanks.

Comment: @user685275  The program just checks whether its input stream (stdin) is a regular file.  If it is, it prints "is a regular file".  If not, it does nothing.  When you redirect from a file, the file is the input stream for the program.  When you pipe from a another process, the read side of the pipe is the input stream.  When you run without piping or redirections from a tty, the tty is the input stream.

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, two results are same. Nothing to say.

For the work principle of `cat a.txt | cat`, the first cat takes argument `a.txt`, then prints its content. You pipe the `stdout` of the first to `stdin` of the second. The second `cat` finds no argument so it reads content from `stdin`, and prints it.

Because you use `<` in the second command, system replaces `stdin` of `cat` with file stream of `a.txt`. Anything else is same as the second cat in the first case.